# How to know whether a dll uses ASLR or not?

Tags: windows, dll, aslr

how to check whether a certain dll uses ASLR or not ?

lets take for example kernel32.dll, does it use ASLR or not ? and how to check other dlls ...

thanks ..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use dumpbin.exe /headers on the DLL.  The DLL characteristics will show "Dynamic base" if ASLR is enabled:

```
...
OPTIONAL HEADER VALUES
             10B magic # (PE32)
            9.00 linker version
           D0000 size of code
           30000 size of initialized data
               0 size of uninitialized data
           132A3 entry point (7DD732A3)
           10000 base of code
           D0000 base of data
        7DD60000 image base (7DD60000 to 7DE6FFFF)
           10000 section alignment
           10000 file alignment
            6.01 operating system version
            6.01 image version
            6.01 subsystem version
               0 Win32 version
          110000 size of image
           10000 size of headers
          1164FD checksum
               3 subsystem (Windows CUI)
             140 DLL characteristics
                   Dynamic base                    <==  Here
                   NX compatible
           40000 size of stack reserve
...
```

Comment: +1, BinScope.exe is an alternative. https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2012/08/15/microsofts-free-security-tools-binscope-binary-analyzer/