# How do you disable ASLR (address space layout randomization) on Windows 7 x64?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-7-x64, aslr

How do you disable ASLR on Windows 7 x64 so that my program will always load the shared CRT at the same address?

Comment: Do you _need_ to do this, or does it just make something easier?

Comment: @unclebrad: I really do *need* to do this.

Comment: Note that this significantly degrades the security of the system and should be done only with the permission of the user.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Right, I *am* the user. (The only user, and the only administrator, in fact. :P)

Comment: @Galaxas0: Haha... IMHO when you're an administrator, you **should** be able to do whatever you want, by definition.

Comment: The shared CRT isn't your DLL, so you can't disable ASLR for it. You can only disable ASLR for EXEs and DLLs that you own (by disabling the DLL_IMAGE_RELOCATABLE flag in the PE header). The reason for this is that Windows Vista and above relocate some key windows binaries during system boot so that they can share the relocated memory across processes - this includes stuff like ntdll, kernel32, gdi32, user32, wininet and sadly for you, mscrt.

Comment: @Mehrdad, this is true, this is true xD. SecurityMatt: You are INDEED allowed to disable CRT ASLR, as an administrator, as it's a registry key- in my answer below.

Comment: @Galaxas0 - Ok, you're allowed to disable ASLR and DEP *system wide* (which is a horrific thing to do - you're literally putting the whole system at risk) but you are not allowed to disable it just in your process.

Comment: ^ This is true, and that's also what I was trying to say to Mehrdad, but I guess he really, really, really needed it.

Comment: Hmm, of course, the day after I answer this question: http://9to5google.com/2012/03/07/vupen-conquers-chrome-at-pwn2own-security-conference-google-must-pay-cash-reward-for-french-teams-hack/ Suspicious much? :D

Comment: @Galaxas0: Lollllll indeed it is O_O

Comment: Yes, indeed. Well, this is what happens when you disable ASLR, so be cautious!

Comment: Don't disable ASLR!  Kittehs die every time someone disables ASLR... Come on, maybe @Mehrdad just needs to test an exploit technique under a VM.

Comment: @SecurityMatt Can you please check this question. Seems you are an expert regarding this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72569189/i-dont-have-the-linker-option-in-visual-studio-2013-how-to-enable-it

Comment: @PrageethLiyanage: I don't know if this is possible with C#, but if it is, you need to use the EditBin tool as someone already told you. You should give that a try and ask about it if you get stuck.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A registry setting is available to forcibly enable or disable ASLR for all executables and libraries and is found at `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\MoveImages`.

Comment: Don't change global system settings to make *your* program work

Comment: +1 I'll try this out. It seems to be what I need, since changing it on a per-program basis won't affect how the (shared) CRT is loaded.

Comment: ^ This. But you should remember that if this is a distributed application, you should not do this, and if it's an ABSOLUTE MUST, prompt the user before programmatically doing it.

Comment: The CRT is mapped for every process independently - even though the CRT might be *loaded* only once (i.e. it only occupies a single place in physical memory), its *virtual address* will be different for every process.

Comment: @Galaxas0: Don't worry, it's only for myself, since I need to disable it to test something. And thanks, it looks like it works well!

Comment: This setting disables ASLR for the entire system, which massively reduces your protection against remote exploit attacks.

Comment: @Paul Betts: Not true. ASLR is per-session, not per-process. Kernel32 is loaded at the same address in all of my processes, but probably at a different address to all of your processes (and your processes will all be the same as well)

Comment: You're right, but only because Kernel32 and ntdll are "magical". Other DLLs will be at random locations

Comment: @Paul Betts: Kernel32 and ntdll are certainly magical, but the same is also true of other DLLs. If someone loads a DLL in process A and then someone opens it again in Process B they'll get the same address (this allows the kernel to have both processes backed by the same pages to save RAM). Consequently if you have Sophos installed, for instance, it will have it's DLLs in every process at the same address. The difference with normal DLLs is that it is possible for them to all become unloaded when everyone gets bored of them, at which point the next load will have a new address.

Comment: Also in the event that the Process B has something in the way of where Process A loaded the DLL, then Process B is forced to relocate it. This is not true of the magical system DLLs which never relocate except at boot

Comment: SecurityMatt, you're kind of blowing my mind here, Upvotes for you!

Comment: Well his name IS SecurityMatt. Security must be his forte. :D

Comment: This didn't work for me (Windows 7 Professional 64bit, SP1). Note however, that that registry key didn't exist so I created it (as a DWORD = 0) and rebooted. (Side note: As a developer it can sometimes be useful to disable ASLR when debugging and investigating issues).

Comment: Update. Sysinternals VMMap shows loaded assemblies in .NET with 'ASLR' against them, however, IE now errors when I try to run it so I suspect I have partially disabled ASLR with this reg key (Since IE failing seems to be one of the symptoms of disabling ASLR).

Comment: Update. SO it looks like the reg key does disable ASLR and that VMMap is merely indicating if an assembly has been marked as supporting/allowing ASLR. The EMET UI also has an option to diable ASLR, and this appears to be a UI over the same reg key (when I used EMET to disable ASLR it recreated the key and set it to zero).

Answer (score 33):

Previously you had to opt in to allowing the linker to use ASLR. Now, [you have to opt out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384887.aspx):

```
/DYNAMICBASE[:NO]
```

(Visual Studio 2012: Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Advanced -> "Randomized Base Address")

You can also do it [programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vclinkertool.randomizedbaseaddress.aspx).

Comment: This is very handy when you have a project you are debugging, and you would prefer that the addresses in your watch window don't change every run.

Comment: Still there in Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: I cant find this place inside VS. (Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Advanced -> "Randomized Base Address"). Plz help me. Using VS 2013

Answer (score 21):

The Enhanced Mitigation Experience Toolkit (EMET), [downloadable from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54264), allows to enable/disable ASLR it on a system or process basis.

Comment: For anyone wondering if EMET would install on Win 10: no, the install fails.

Comment: EMET has been end-of-lifed, but you can achieve the same using the windows defender exploit protection module. Windows Security > App & browser control > Exploit protection, set "Randomise memory allocations" to "Off by default" either system-wide or per-program. Only for windows 10+ though so I'm not writing it as an answer since OP asked for win7.

Answer (score 0):

## Method 1 (by disabling it globally)

*(as noted in above [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560993/how-do-you-disable-aslr-address-space-layout-randomization-on-windows-7-x64#comment12120493_9561263), that might not be desirable for your system and maybe you can restore that back after your small task is done)*

from cmd/Batch you can try adding these two values:

```
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management" /v MoveImages /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\kernel" /v MitigationOptions /t REG_BINARY /d "00000000000000000000000000000000" /f
```

## Method 2 - disabling for just specific app

from powershell:

```
Get-Item -Path "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\*.exe" | %{ Set-ProcessMitigation -Name $_.Name -Disable ForceRelocateImages }
```

or with the help of experimental app:

```
cd %tmp%
wget http://www.didierstevens.com/files/software/setdllcharacteristics_v0_0_0_1.zip -o sdc.zip
Expand-Archive -Path sdc.zip -DestinationPath ./
./setdllcharacteristics.exe -d "C:\path\to\your\app.exe"
```

Comment: Isn't there already an answer saying the same thing? Did you ChatGPT this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/9561263/541686