# can i start a program without ASLR on Windows?

Tags: winapi, aslr

is there some way to start a program with ASLR disabled on Windows? like on Posix one would do

```
posix_spawnattr_t attrs={0}; 
posix_spawnattr_setflags(&attrs, _POSIX_SPAWN_DISABLE_ASLR);
posix_spawnp(NULL, "./program.exe", NULL, &attrs,...);
```

and then program.exe would be started without ASLR.. but i have no idea how to do it on Windows (couldn't find any relevant info when looking through CreateProcessW docs either)

[this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9801657/1067003) suggest that Microsoft's `Enhanced Mitigation Experience Toolkit (EMET)` could indeed disable ASLR on a per-process basis, which suggest that it is possible (or at the very least, it was possible on Windows 7)

(also this is not a duplicate of `how to disable ASLR on Windows` because i don't want to disable ASLR globally, but i know there is a registry key that can globally disable ASLR)

Comment: FWIW, removing the `IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE` flag from PE header may work, but this will break the digital signature checks if the file is signed.