# fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x13A1410/0x13D1410

Tags: bootstrap-4, cygwin, mismatch

I was trying to install `poppe` using this command `npm install popper --save` but I got a bunch of errors like this error message:

```
      3 [main] sh (28644) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x13A1410/0x13D1410.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
      1 [main] sh 956 fork: child -1 - forked process 28644 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
      2 [main] sh (24104) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x13A1410/0x11B1410.
```

What is the problem and how can I fix?

Comment: Already answered at SuperUser: https://superuser.com/questions/1380238/how-can-i-fix-the-error-fatal-error-cygheap-base-mismatch-detected-when-usin

Comment: @JulianKnight: Thank you. I added `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\sh.exe` for example, but it opens a pop-up with meny options that I can check them. Which option(s) should I check? Just both ASLR options?

Comment: It is the force randomisation option that is the issue, just turn that off.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cygwin/Git error cygheap base mismatch detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107319/cygwin-git-error-cygheap-base-mismatch-detected)