# Are "popper" and "popper.js" two different packages in npm?

Tags: npm, bootstrap-4, popper.js, react-popper, popperjs

I am following a tutorial that uses this command to install popper:
`npm install popper --save`. But when I tried it got this error message: [fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x13A1410/0x13D1410](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56201929/fatal-error-cygheap-base-mismatch-detected-0x13a1410-0x13d1410?noredirect=1#comment99039307_56201929)

So I searched to find the github page of this library and found this page: https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js but I saw it suggests this command to install it: `npm install popper.js --save` and it's different from my tutorial. Now I like to know are these to libraries different? What is the github page of the `poppe` not `popper.js` if they are different?

I also must mention that I don't say python popper library. I want the javascript version that used by `bootstrap4`.

Comment: yes, they're different

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two different packages:

**Popper: Realtime Cross-Browser Automation**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/popper

https://github.com/pemrouz/popper

**Popper.js: A library used to position poppers in web applications.**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/popper.js

https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js

https://popper.js.org/