# Why can't I fix the cygwin1.dll mismatch issue?

Tags: cygwin

I'm trying to execute a .sh script (that wasn't written by me) and I get the following error:

> 0 [main] echo (5320) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\echo.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x180343408/0x180317408.
> This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
> Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
> and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
> reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
> installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
> are unable to find another cygwin DLL.

I tried to follow the instructions in the error but I only have one cygwin1.dll file.

So I tried to execute the following command in a git bash shell:

> /c/cygwin/bin/man

and I get:

> 0 [main] man (11952) C:\cygwin\bin\man.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap
> base mismatch detected - 0x180317408/0x180343408. This problem is
> probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL. Search
> for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility and
> delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version
> *should* reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested

I already tried to disable ASRL options in the exploit protection panel (as suggested by somebody) and reboot but that didn't fix the problem.

If I write

> which -a cygwin1.dll

I get:

> /c/cygwin/bin/cygwin1.dll
>
> /c/cygwin/bin/cygwin1.dll

It looks like I have two cygwin1.dll but actually I only have one..
I have been searching for a possible solution since days but nothing seems to work for me.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cygwin/Git error cygheap base mismatch detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107319/cygwin-git-error-cygheap-base-mismatch-detected)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the error message is mentioning `cygwin1.dll`, it is misleading as the `Git for Windows` is using `MSYS` and the file was renamed `msys-2.0.dll`

Unfortunately the MSYS team forgot to change the error messages when they imported and modified the `Cygwin` source:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem while trying to build a certain C/C++ project from source in the Git Bash Terminal.
Based on the previous answers by @Harry and @matzeri it seems that Git Bash is what is causing this problem. To resolve it I had to disable ASLR for all executables in my Cygwin install folder (Usuall C:\cygwin64) using the command

> `Get-Item -Path "C:\cygwin64\bin\*.exe" | %{ Set-ProcessMitigation -Name $_.Name -Disable ForceRelocateImages }`

I restarted the computer and then switched to using Cygwin Terminal and compiled from there.

**NB:** Cygwin Terminal comes by default with Cygwin installation

[image]

Comment: This answer put me on right track. When I upgraded to latest npm on windows 10 using GitBash npm started getting the first error message from question. It started working when I found and renamed the file `<User>/anaconda3/Library/usr/bin/msys-2.0.dll`

Answer (score 0):

- Find all the `msys-2.0.dll`'s on your machine and add the suffix `.bkp` to them.
- Wherever you found them at, copy `"C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\msys-2.0.dll"` to those locations.

[image: VoidTools Everything screenshot of msys-2.0.dlls]

Notes:

- If you were to copy from `C:\msys64\usr\bin\msys-2.0.dll` to all other locations, then you lose that nice additional text at the end that shows the branch you're on `(master)` [image: Shows what branch you're on]

  - Same goes if you just decide to delete all the extra dlls and just add `C:\msys64\usr\bin` to your path, there must be a dependencies it looks for relative to the directory it normally resides.
- Because apparently I skimmed the selected answer and missed the part about `msys-2.0.dll`, I had to figure this out myself.  For future reference:

  - Run [`listdlls -r -v -d msys-2.0.dll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/listdlls)
  - Check Base, Path, and Version info for discrepancies.