# How can I solve the problem between cygwin and my RStudio terminal?

Tags: terminal, cygwin, rstudio, rtools

I have installed RStudioand after a few minute i get this message on my terminal board:

> "0 [main] ls (23240) C:\rtools40\usr\bin\ls.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x180331408/0x180316408.
>   This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
>   Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
>   and delete all but the most recent version.
>   The most recent version *should* reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have installed the cygwin distribution.
>   Rebooting is also suggested if you are unable to find another cygwin DLL."

And the problem is that I don't found the file cygwin1.dll in my computer and I don't have more version of cygwin.
Thank you in advance for the response.

Comment: similar issue to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60507083/why-cant-i-fix-the-cygwin1-dll-mismatch-issue/60525817#60525817 `While the error message is mentioning cygwin1.dll, it is misleading as it is using MSYS and the file was renamed msys-2.0.dll`