# netbeans8.2 + msys2_64 + mingw64 + cygwin64 + C project build errors

Tags: c, cygwin, netbeans-8, mingw-w64, msys2

On new HP tower G4 workstation with Xeon E2224G processor, Windows 10 pro for wokstations OS build 19042.746.

install netbeans 8.2

Install msys2_64 and mingw64

set path e:\msys64\usr\bin; e:\msys64\mingw64\bin; %PATH%

Verify that make,sh,bash,rm and more are in e:\msys64\usr\bin
configure netbeans for C project and try to clean and build and get this error:

```
'No shell found. Cannot proceed. Please install either CYGWIN or Msys.'
```

OK then, install cygwin.
Now get this error:

```
'1 [main] rm (7980) E:\cygwin64\bin\rm.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x180345408/0x180347408.'
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
cygcheck -c gives
base-cygwin          3.8-1              OK
base-files           4.3-2              OK
cygwin               3.1.7-1            OK
```

I have searched and there is only one cygwin1.dll

```
frank@FRANK_NEW ~
$ which cygwin1.dll
/usr/bin/cygwin1.dll
```

I have restarted the machine several times to no avail.

I have been using netbeans and mingw then msys/mingw for about 10 years and
have the combination working on other desktop and laptop machines, but have
not had this problem.

Comment: do not mix Cygwin and Msys. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60507083/why-cant-i-fix-the-cygwin1-dll-mismatch-issue

Comment: Can you call "sh" from the command line?

Comment: yes I can call sh

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies above. The problem here is the different ways that PATH is handled by Windows 10 Pro and Windows 10 Pro for Workstations.

For Win10 Pro
define a user variable 'MSYS_HOME' give it a value of 'E:\msys64\usr\bin'
now put that in the system path i.e.
some system path;%MSYS_HOME%;more system path
Netbeans will find the tools rm, sh, make, etc and complete the clean and build of the project.

for Win10 Pro for Worksations
the above did not work. Netbeans would not build the project and give the error
'No shell found. Cannot proceed. Please install either CYGWIN or Msys.'
the path has to be set in the system path directly i.e.
some system path;E:\msys64\usr\bin;more system path
this made Netbeans work correctly to perform clean and build.