# Mysys2 error: Execution failed (Unexpected exit code: 254): "C\msys64\usr\bin\bash.exe --login -c exit"

Tags: cygwin

I was installing Mysys2 then a textbox popped up. I did some research and realize I didn't have cygwin on my computer. So I installed cygwin. But that did not fix anything.

[Textbox popped up while installing Mysys2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63IKD.png)

I also try to run that code in bash then an error appeared:

```
    0 [main] bash (19644) C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x1156408/0x1106408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
      0 [main] bash 696 dofork: child -1 - forked process 19644 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash (9136) C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x1156408/0x11D6408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
1122281 [main] bash 696 dofork: child -1 - forked process 9136 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash (13760) C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x1156408/0x11D6408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
3238823 [main] bash 696 dofork: child -1 - forked process 13760 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash (19628) C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x1156408/0x10F6408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
7359054 [main] bash 696 dofork: child -1 - forked process 19628 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash (19868) C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x1156408/0x11B6408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
15473267 [main] bash 696 dofork: child -1 - forked process 19868 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

But I did install cygwin and there is cygwin1.dll in C:\cygwin64\bin

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60507083/why-cant-i-fix-the-cygwin1-dll-mismatch-issue

Comment: What do you mean? That is not my question! You should help me solve my problem instead of showing some similar questions. Those similar questions do not help!

Comment: You do not need to have cygwin installed to install or run msys2. It is possible that you have too much stuff in your path. Cygwin should not be in your path except when running a cygwin shell. You may have different versions of bash interfering with each other. Git bash for example, should not be in your path. Use `where bash` in cmd or `which -a bash` in bash as required to find duplicates.

Comment: @BlackJackMC  MSYS2 is not using  `cygwin1.dll`; the error message is misleading as their library is called `msys-2.0.dll`. I agree with Doug that you need to clean a bit your PATH as probably you have multiple version of the MSYS2 enviroment

Comment: Hello. try turning off mandatory ASLR settings. it solved mine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem is caused by a feature in Windows Security called Mandatory ASLR (thanks to [dariush-mazlumi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70995093/mysys2-error-execution-failed-unexpected-exit-code-254-c-msys64-usr-bin-ba/78248269#comment130385341_70995093)).

Here are some ways to solve the problem:

- **Option 1** (I used this one): turn off Mandatory ALSR by going to Windows Security > App & browser control > Exploit protection settings > System settings
- **Option 2** (I find it helpful): add all of binaries in `C:\msys2\usr\bin\` to Windows Security > App & browser control > Exploit protection settings > Program settings ([source](https://github.com/appveyor/ci/issues/3777#issuecomment-1848799949))