# ssh (Suddenly) not available in Windows Git Bash

Tags: git-bash

Hey there I'm a anaconda + Git Bash user in Windows, and after some windows system update, I found my git bash cannot run ssh anymore.
Here is the error

`$ ssh       0 [main] ssh (5464) C:\Users\usrname\miniconda3\Library\usr\bin\ssh.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x180340408/0x180331408. This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL. Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should* reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you are unable to find another cygwin DLL.`

I searched the `cygwinl.dll` file in my system, yet it does not exist. Also I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107319/cygwin-git-error-cygheap-base-mismatch-detected)
and none of them makes any difference. Amazingly in windows powershell and cmd, ssh works fine. So the problem is just git Bash. I still in deep love with Git bash (makes my git, coda consistent with ssh), so any idea how to fix it?

Bth I also tried reinstall git bash, no difference at all.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an [ASLR setting to remove](https://superuser.com/a/1380239/141) ([**Address space layout randomization**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization))

> In order to fix this issue:
>
> - open the [Exploit Protection](https://www.ghacks.net/2017/10/25/configure-windows-defender-exploit-guard-in-windows-10/) settings,
> - switch to the Program Settings tab and
> - add the executable names listed in the errors (you may have quite a number).