# How to install cgal in windows 10?

Tags: c++, cgal, msys2, vcpkg

I wanted to install cgal 5.5.1 in windows10 with the command: ".\vcpkg install cgal:x64-windows"
But I got the following Error:

```
 0 [main] perl (21212) C:\src\vcpkg\downloads\tools\msys2\583ad6e4115a307a\usr\bin\perl.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x1322408/0xDE2408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_execute_required_process.cmake:96 (message):
    Command failed: C:/src/vcpkg/downloads/tools/msys2/583ad6e4115a307a/usr/bin/bash.exe --noprofile --norc --debug -c "autoreconf -vfi"
    Working Directory: C:/src/vcpkg/buildtrees/gmp/src/v6.2.1-0c723d4b6f.clean/
    Error code: 127
    See logs for more information:
      C:\src\vcpkg\buildtrees\gmp\autoconf-x64-windows-err.log

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  scripts/cmake/vcpkg_configure_make.cmake:601 (vcpkg_execute_required_process)
  ports/gmp/portfile.cmake:82 (vcpkg_configure_make)
  scripts/ports.cmake:147 (include)


error: building gmp:x64-windows failed with: BUILD_FAILED
error: Please ensure you're using the latest port files with `git pull` and `vcpkg update`.
Then check for known issues at:
    https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+in%3Atitle+gmp
You can submit a new issue at:
    https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/new?template=report-package-build-failure.md&title=[gmp]+Build+error
Include '[gmp] Build error' in your bug report title, the following version information in your bug description, and attach any relevant failure logs from above.
    vcpkg-tool version: 2022-11-10-5fdee72bc1fceca198fb1ab7589837206a8b81ba
    vcpkg-scripts version: 5d1f18840 2022-12-06 (10 hours ago)
```

You can see the log file in following.
Could you please help me?

```
Computing installation plan...
The following packages will be built and installed:
    cgal[core]:x64-windows -> 5.5.1
  * gmp[core]:x64-windows -> 6.2.1#14
  * mpfr[core]:x64-windows -> 4.1.0#7
Additional packages (*) will be modified to complete this operation.
Detecting compiler hash for triplet x64-windows...
Restored 0 package(s) from C:\Users\sajad.mohseni\AppData\Local\vcpkg\archives in 269.7 us. Use --debug to see more details.
Installing 1/3 gmp:x64-windows...
Building gmp[core]:x64-windows...
-- Using cached gmp-6.2.1.tar.xz.
-- Using cached gmp-arm64-asm-fix-5f32dbc41afc.patch.
-- Cleaning sources at C:/src/vcpkg/buildtrees/gmp/src/v6.2.1-0c723d4b6f.clean. Use --editable to skip cleaning for the packages you specify.
-- Extracting source C:/src/vcpkg/downloads/gmp-6.2.1.tar.xz
-- Applying patch asmflags.patch
-- Applying patch cross-tools.patch
-- Applying patch subdirs.patch
-- Applying patch msvc_symbol.patch
-- Applying patch arm64-coff.patch
-- Applying patch C:/src/vcpkg/downloads/gmp-arm64-asm-fix-5f32dbc41afc.patch
-- Using source at C:/src/vcpkg/buildtrees/gmp/src/v6.2.1-0c723d4b6f.clean
-- Found external ninja('1.10.2').
-- Getting CMake variables for x64-windows
-- Getting CMake variables for x64-windows
-- Using cached msys-gzip-1.11-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst.
-- Using cached msys-bash-5.1.008-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst.
-- Using cached msys-autoconf-2.71-3-any.pkg.tar.zst.
-- Using cached msys-diffutils-3.8-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst.
-- Using cached msys-binutils-2.37-5-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst.
-- Using cached msys-libtool-2.4.6-9-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz.
-- Using cached msys-file-5.41-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst.
-- Using cached msys-zlib-1.2.11-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz.
-- Using cached msys-libbz2-1.0.8-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst.
-- Using cached msys-coreutils-8.32-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst.
-- Using cached msys-grep-3.0-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz.
-- Using cached msys-sed-4.8-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst.
-- Using cached msys-libpcre-8.45-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst.
-- Using cached msys-m4-1.4.19-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst.
-- Using cached msys-automake-wrapper-11-4-any.pkg.tar.zst.
-- Using cached msys-gawk-5.1.0-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst.
-- Using cached msys-mpfr-4.1.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst.
-- Using cached msys-gmp-6.2.1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst.
-- Using cached msys-libreadline-8.1.001-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst.
-- Using cached msys-ncurses-6.2-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst.
-- Using cached msys-automake1.16-1.16.3-3-any.pkg.tar.zst.
-- Using cached msys-perl-5.32.1-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst.
-- Using cached msys-libcrypt-2.1-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst.
-- Using cached msys-pkg-config-0.29.2-4-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst.
-- Using cached msys-make-4.3-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst.
-- Using cached msys-findutils-4.8.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst.
-- Using cached msys-libintl-0.21-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst.
-- Using cached msys-libiconv-1.16-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst.
-- Using cached msys-gcc-libs-11.2.0-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst.
-- Using cached msys-msys2-runtime-3.2.0-8-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst.
-- Using cached msys-which-2.21-4-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst.
-- Applying patch C:/src/vcpkg/scripts/msys/compile_wrapper_consider_clang-cl.patch
-- Using msys root at C:/src/vcpkg/downloads/tools/msys2/583ad6e4115a307a
-- Generating configure for x64-windows
      0 [main] perl (21212) C:\src\vcpkg\downloads\tools\msys2\583ad6e4115a307a\usr\bin\perl.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x1322408/0xDE2408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_execute_required_process.cmake:96 (message):
    Command failed: C:/src/vcpkg/downloads/tools/msys2/583ad6e4115a307a/usr/bin/bash.exe --noprofile --norc --debug -c "autoreconf -vfi"
    Working Directory: C:/src/vcpkg/buildtrees/gmp/src/v6.2.1-0c723d4b6f.clean/
    Error code: 127
    See logs for more information:
      C:\src\vcpkg\buildtrees\gmp\autoconf-x64-windows-err.log

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  scripts/cmake/vcpkg_configure_make.cmake:601 (vcpkg_execute_required_process)
  ports/gmp/portfile.cmake:82 (vcpkg_configure_make)
  scripts/ports.cmake:147 (include)


error: building gmp:x64-windows failed with: BUILD_FAILED
error: Please ensure you're using the latest port files with `git pull` and `vcpkg update`.
Then check for known issues at:
    https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+in%3Atitle+gmp
You can submit a new issue at:
    https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/new?template=report-package-build-failure.md&title=[gmp]+Build+error
Include '[gmp] Build error' in your bug report title, the following version information in your bug description, and attach any relevant failure logs from above.
    vcpkg-tool version: 2022-11-10-5fdee72bc1fceca198fb1ab7589837206a8b81ba
    vcpkg-scripts version: 5d1f18840 2022-12-06 (10 hours ago)
```

Comment: did you do what the message tells you?

Comment: I hot apologize for this solution. Try restarting the PC. Not kidding. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107319/cygwin-git-error-cygheap-base-mismatch-detected)